# Best name for a chord consisting of D - E - F?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory, tablature

What is the best notation for this guitar chord?

```
    V
о─┬───┬───┬───┬───┬── e
──┼───┼─•─┼───┼───┼── f
──┼───┼───┼─•─┼───┼── d
о─┼───┼───┼───┼───┼── d
×─┼───┼───┼───┼───┼──
×─┴───┴───┴───┴───┴──
```

6th and 5th strings don’t play, 1st and 4th are open, 2nd is on the 6th fret, 3rd is on the 7th fret. So the chord consists of three different notes: D, E and F. Can this chord be named Dm + something, or Dm9 + something, or some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it a Dm(add9). A Dm(add9) is spelled:

```
D - F - A - E
```

The only note you are missing is A which is the 5th which is commonly omitted.

Comment: add9, not add2?

Comment: Add2 isn't really a thing : http://music.stackexchange.com/a/26761/7222

Comment: If it had to be a 2 you could say "sus2", which is almost always a misnomer (not really suspended). In this case "add9" is clearly best.

Comment: @Dmitry  Traditional harmony tries to label each pitch in thirds, where it makes sense. Normally seconds are not labeled as ninths unless there is a seventh in the chord, but most people hear the D E F combination as a minor ninth.  Personally, I would even omit the 'add', but the ideal notation is just to represent the notes using staff notation so that there is no ambiguity.